# How to distribute MATLAB's parfor workers between GPUs AND CPUs (cores)?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, gpgpu, distributed-computing, parfor

I have a computation that has the structure of a binary tree, where at each node a bunch of highly vectorized functions take the output of the previous branches to produce new branch(es) (nodes on the same level are independent). Since the functions are vectorized, they run well both on CPU or GPU, the latter naturally giving substantially faster execution.

I will soon have access to 4-GPU 2-CPU workstation to run my code on and I would like to use it as optimally as I can. I understand how to use `parfor` on the GPUs only or on the CPUs' cores only, but I would like to reasonably distribute the workload between the GPUs and the CPU, since GPU execution only leaves so many CPU cores at idle, and even though they are much slower than the GPUs, they are still fast enough to have noticeable impact on the total execution time.

**(Q1)** Since the functions in each node are vectorized, is it actually reasonable to run independent nodes in 1-node-per-core mode? Or does that strictly depend on the particular case? Is there a "rule of the thumb" for such dilemmas?

**(Q2)** Assuming in **(Q1)** that simultaneous execution of 1 node per core is suboptimal, is there a way to assign several CPU cores to one worker?

**(Q3)** Is there a way to distribute the `parfor` workers between GPUs and CPUs in an *efficient* way?

Here is what I don't consider particularly *efficient* in **(Q3)**: depending on the loop index, the loop instance can execute the GPU code on a given `gpuDevice` or on CPU (core). Knowing the performance difference between GPU and CPU execution, one can deduce a suitable proportion of the indices assigned to CPU execution. The problem with this is that `parfor` does not pick the loop indices in any particular order, which in turn can easily lead to instances where it tries to execute two independent tasks on same GPU, which is inefficient since it will have to serialize the tasks.

Thanks!